# Custom fields design for multiclient application

Tags: laravel, database-design

I have a question releated to application design. I have a ecommerce application which is used by 9 clients. Every client has the same copy of application with different frontend template. App is designed under laravel and it's updating on every customer server to keep up-to-date. So every app have the same backend("engine"), same database design etc.

Problem is that two of the clients wants a custom fields to for CRUD pages. With current update mechanism every client will get those fields which is not what i want.

I've been thinking about adding separate table to database to keep there a configuration of all fields - like a map of table columns. So when app is used controller will call  configuration table to get list of fields and foreach them in view.

```html
+---+---------------+-------------------+------------+
|id |controller     | field_name        |field_type  |
+---+---------------+-------------------+------------+
| 1 | products      | price_retail      | integer    |
| 2 | manufacturers | name              | varchar    |
| 3 | manufacturers | logo              | varchar    |
| 4 | manufacturers | custom_for_client | integer    |
+---+---------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Is it a valid - good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by *'custom fields'*? Different **type** or different **name** or a **new** field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you plan to do with these "fields", I can only make suggestions.

Have you considered the use of a json column to store data for fields that aren't applicable to all users?

**Database Migration**

```
...
$table->json('meta')->nullable();
...
```

**Model**

```
...
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        ...
        'meta' => 'array',
        ...
    ];
...
```

You can then access the "fields" within this json object like so:

```
$model->meta['column'];
```

or iterate over then like so:

```
collect($model->meta)->each(function ($column) {});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: This would allow you to store as many additional "fields" as you like in as many combinations as you like for your different users without resorting to new database tables  and maps